# СУБД Java и какую выбрать?

Tags: java

Новичок и хотел бы узнать какую СУБД мне "учить"? Открыл hh.ru посмотрел и везде пишут просто: SQL, я знаю что это язык структурированных запросов, а каких средах производится работа на сегодняшний день, как с Java "контачит" SQL и тд. Дайте пожалуйста подробный ответ, опишите пожалуйста, что лучше использовать, что актуально и тд.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Никто вам не насоветует так как вам надо. Каждый напишет свою любимую/используемую в проектах СУБД, но никто не знаетгде и как вы будете применять ее. Для учебных целей можно юзать PostgreSQL, MySQL. Есть какая-то штука под название NoSQL (сам не юзал, не знаю что за зверь, но используют вроде для тестирования). Еще когда-то 1 раз использовал Derby.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос поставлен не совсем корректно, но всё-таки попробую ответить.

> Открыл hh.ru посмотрел и везде пишут просто: SQL, я знаю что это язык
>   структурированных запросов, а каких средах производится работа на
>   сегодняшний день

Описания вакансий на hh.ru, к глубокому сожалению, часто пишут не особо компетентные люди. Поэтому, можно и не такое встретить.

СУБД достаточно много, у всех есть плюсы и минусы, и потому какую из них учить точно Вам не скажет никто. Всё зависит от того на чём построен тот или иной конкретный проект.

Лично я бы посоветовал ориентироваться на, если можно так сказать, "большую четвёрку": Oracle, MS SQL Server, MySQL, PostgresQL.

> как с Java "контачит" SQL

Основных способа 2:

- JDBC;
- ORM (например, Hibernate).

Как с ними работать, тема для отдельного разговора. Благо, есть документация. Как официальная, так и в виде статей в блогах и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо большое, вопрос поставлен не совсем корректно, потому что я новичок и только учусь, я просто даже многое еще не понимаю, а информация по java обычно 2010-2013 года, а английский я учу, но нет такого уровня чтобы понимать документацию, я ели еще на русском понимаю :D, спасибо за ответ

Comment: Без англ. в ИТ делать нечего.

Comment: Поэтому я и записался на курсы и хожу изучаю:D

Comment: А SQLite?......

Comment: @Данил, SQLite используется только как встраиваемая БД для локального ПО или под Android (но, там все ли почти все новые проекты уже пишут на Kotlin).
Java сейчас это в 99% случаев про большие системы для таких же больших корпораций. SQLite там делать нечего.